# Can SimpleInjector register an initializer for generic types at runtime?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Can I register initializers for Generic types with SimpleInjector at runtime? (see the last line of code below)

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    Type baseTypeGeneric = typeof(Sample<>);
    public void BootStrap(Container container)
    {
        var types =
            from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where type.Namespace == "NS.xyz" 
            select type;

        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            Type baseType = baseTypeGeneric.MakeGenericType(type);

            if (type.BaseType == baseType)
            {
                container.Register(type);
            }

            //how do I get this line to work?
            container.RegisterInitializer<Sample<[type]>>(
                x => container.InjectProperties(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution as actually rather simple: implement a non-generic interface on `Sample<T>`. This allows you to just register a single delegate for all sample types:

```cs
public interface ISample { }

public abstract class Sample<T> : ISample { }

public void Bootstrapper(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterInitializer<ISample>(
        instance => container.InjectProperties(instance));
}
```

Since `RegisterInitializer` will be applied for all types that implement `ISample`, you just need one registration.

But to be honest, you should be very careful with applying property injection since this leads to container configuration that is hard to verify.  When injecting dependencies into constructors,  the container will throw an exception when a dependency is missing.  With property injection on the other hand,  a missing dependency is simply skipped and no exception is thrown. For this reason the [InjectProperties method was deprecated](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/injectproperties-is-deprecated.html) in v2.6. Please review your strategy. Perhaps you should reconsider. If you are in doubt and like some feedback on your design; post a new question here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: you're a bit of a legend ;-). I'm using this in a very specific scenario, injecting LazyLoading handlers into my data classes - there is not a fixed number across all instances. I'll look again into using the constructor but I do need a default empty constructor.